# A function to increment numbers within parentheses/brackets by a specified amount

Tags: r, regex

I have a string of this form.I want to increase the numbers within bracket in this string  by 15.

Kindly suggest some regex code in R for this task. Have read about extracting numbers from brackets/parentheses in this forum. But doesn't help in this specific case.

```
String=
" John was going .[1]  Sam was Walking [2,3]. Rita was reading [4] . Donald was cooking with 3 spoons [5-7]"
```

Desired Output.

```
"John was going .[16]  Sam was Walking [17,18]. Rita was reading [19] Donald was cooking with 3 spoons [20-22]"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`gsubfn` is like `gsub` except the replacement string is a replacement *function* that takes the match as its input and replaces it with its output.  The function can be expressed using formula notation (as we do here) or the usual function notation.

The inner `gsubfn` takes a `[...]` string and replaces the numbers in it with those numbers plus 15 and the outer `gsubfn` passes the `[...]` to the inner one.  Note that the regular expression `\\[.*?\\]` matches a left square bracket `\\[` followed by the shortest string `.*?` until the next right square bracket `\\]` .

This solution is compact (only one line), only uses relatively simple regular expressions, does not overwrite its input and is vectorized (i.e. `String` can be a vector).

```
library(gsubfn)

gsubfn("\\[.*?\\]", ~ gsubfn("\\d+", ~ as.numeric(x) + 15, x), String)
## " John was going .[16]  Sam was Walking [17,18]. Rita was reading [19] . Donald was cooking with 3 spoons [20-22]"
```

If it is sufficient to increment all numbers then it could be simplified to:

```
gsubfn("\\d+", ~ as.numeric(x) + 15, String)
## [1] " John was going .[16]  Sam was Walking [17,18]. Rita was reading [19] . Donald was cooking with 18 spoons [20-22]"
```

Answer (score 2):

Similar to @G. Grothendieck's answer, this can also easily be achieved with `stringr`'s `str_replace_all` function, which accepts a replacement function rather than a constant. In this case, there is only one function call needed:

```
library(stringr)

str_replace_all(String, "\\d+(?=[^\\[]*\\])", function(x) as.numeric(x) + 15)
```

**Output:**

```
[1] " John was going .[16]  Sam was Walking [17,18]. Rita was reading [19] . Donald was cooking with 3 spoons [20-22]"
```

Or alternatively, a Base R solution:

```
pos <- gregexpr("\\d+(?=[^[]*\\])", String, perl = TRUE)
num <- as.numeric(regmatches(String, pos)[[1]]) + 15
regmatches(String, pos)[[1]] <- num
```

**Output:**

```
[1] " John was going .[16]  Sam was Walking [17,18]. Rita was reading [19] . Donald was cooking with 3 spoons [20-22]"
```

**Notes:**

1. The regular expression `\\d+(?=[^[]*\\])` matches any digits one or more times (`\\d+`) that is followed by (`(?=...)`) a series of non-opening-bracket characters zero or more times (`[^[]*`) and a closing bracket (`\\]`). This effectively matches only digits within brackets.
2. `gregexpr` takes the regex and returns all matching positions within `String`. `perl = TRUE` enables lookarounds.
3. `regmatches` takes the positions returned by `gregexpr` and returns the actual matching strings.
4. A second call to `regmatches` is used to replace the bracketed digits with the new value from `num`

Comment: @r2evans You're right, I missed the 3 in the example

Comment: The reason I knew is b/c I started with the same code and found it before posting an answer. Your use of `perl=` and regex-lookaround is what I came up with, too, nice.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that maybe we could stat with this expression to capture the numbers:

```
\[(\d+(?:[,-]\d+)?)\]
```

then, we would just add 15 to those.

In the right panel of [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/bkVAFR/1/), the expression is further explained, if you might be interested.

Answer (score -1):

```
s = "John was going .[1]  Sam was Walking [2,3]. Rita was reading [4] . Donald was cooking with 3 spoons [5-7]"

import re

s = re.sub(r'\[([\d,-]+)\]', lambda g: re.sub(r'\d+', lambda gg: str(int(gg.group(0)) + 15), g.group(0)), s)

print(s)
```

Prints:

```
John was going .[16]  Sam was Walking [17,18]. Rita was reading [19] . Donald was cooking with 3 spoons [20-22]
```